# GED instead of finishing school

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate

Are there any drawbacks to dropping out of school and completing a GED instead of finishing and getting a diploma?

I am in the midwest United States and am currently unemployed. I would eventually like to have a job focused on computing and was wondering if getting a GED would let me start college early.

Comment: what do you want to do in life?

Comment: you should edit your question and add some context. Your current location, your current job, what you want to achieve by doing either (GED of diplomal), what are your skills and interests. What kind of job you like to do in the future. Right now your questions is a very opinion-based and a bad fit for this website.

Comment: What is your motivation for starting college early? Unless you've already exhausted your high school's offerings in (at least) math, computers, and English, it seems like doing that would be better (or at least cheaper) than taking essentially the same courses in college.

Comment: @cag51 High school offerings are cheap, but they are often also low quality.  Starting college early can be hugely beneficial for certain hard-working students.  If you consider inflation in college tuition, early college can save money.  Early college graduation leads to more years of work before retirement.  This adds to peak earning years, which can be a huge financial advantage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the high school diploma is viewed better for getting jobs than the GED.  Also by colleges.  GED is (probably properly) viewed as a bit of a degraded HS diploma.

That said, a GED is still far better than nothing.  And of course, you can go on to many great things in life without a HS diploma.  Know a guy retiring as an O-6 in the Navy, who ran away from home, entered the fleet, ended up at USNA (i.e. college) and then had a professional job.

It's kind of unclear what sort of scenario you are describing.  If you're in high school, get it done in school.  No advantage to dropping out for a GED, if the plan is eventual college and a professional job.  Different scenario if you want to work a trade, but even then I would still urge to get the HS diploma.  Our society is overvaluing college...people here will disagree because they are employees of "Big College", but there's no reason for baristas to have college degrees.

Of course, if you're a couple years out of school (to draw a line, let's say older than 19), just get the GED, easiest fastest and move on.

As far as the computer career counseling (especially your comment on being unemployed), I would urge you to get a job, any job (assuming you're over 19).  Even if it's not in computers, just get something, so you're working. It's good to be productive and will help your self esteem and respect from others.

Also, there are still many technician types of jobs/training in the broadly defined IT industry that are available sans college, sometimes with some training.  If you go that route, do something where the training is at night (so you can work in the day).  Maybe you eventually do some night school college work also, but don't make that an immediate objective.  Also look carefully over the different training options.  There are some that are snaky (expensive, not very useful) and others that are high bang for the buck and high bang for the time.You need to research them.

One practical note, if you're just 16-19, having family disputes and considering dropping out and moving on because of that, don't.  Suck it up and get the HS diploma.  It's pretty common for there to be friction (especially young man with old bull) at that stage in life.  The military used to harvest huge amounts of talented people from this dynamic who entered sans HS diploma.  It is still possible to some extent but even there, getting more restrictive.

Answer (score 4):

> I am in the midwest United States ... and was wondering if getting a GED would let me start college early.

In my experience, it's common for high schools in the US to allow some sort of mechanism for earning college credits during high school (often through a community college, but also potentially through a major university; many of my friends did the former, I did the latter on a limited basis).

If your goal is to get a jump start on college, this would be a much better mechanism than dropping out and getting a GED. Names for these programs include "concurrent enrollment" and "post-secondary enrollment options." Talk to a counselor at your school.

Comment: For a typical student who doesn't mind doing the courses, and whose high school is not particularly challenging, I think this is probably true.  One of my students just mentioned she has an associate's degree coming out of HS.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to check entrance requirements, and ideally talk with a counselor, at one or more colleges in your area. Some may prefer high school graduation to GED. Graduation implies an ability to follow-through and finish things which is important for college success.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get into college early, you do not need a GED or a high school diploma.

There are quite a few colleges that allow students to enrol early.  Simon's Rock College exclusively enrols students who are starting college early.  Most of their students do not get a high school diploma or GED, but many of them have got graduate degrees.  This model is increasingly being copied by other colleges.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_college_high_school

If your goal is to get a job involving computing, you do not necessarily need any kind of degree or diploma; a record of successful projects may be sufficient.  This is especially true if you want to start your own business.  However, a traditional bachelor's degree in computer science will look good to many employers in that industry.  A GED or high school diploma will count for little in a software company where most of the employees have bachelor's degrees.

Comment: Don't lie.  Some companies do require a GED, such as McDonald's.  You won't want to work there if you have a bachelor's degree.